# Error: Use of undeclared type BindableObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, aws-amplify

I’m following this tutorial for SwiftUI amplify app where I came across this error when creating a final class which conforms to Bindable object.

`Error:Use of undeclared type 'BindableObject'`

```
import Combine  
import SwiftUI  
import AWSAppSync  

final class TalkStore: BindableObject {
/*
    Required by SwiftUI
*/
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<TalkStore, Never>()
    var listTalks: [ListTodosQuery.Data.ListTodo.Item] {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    //We will be using this later.
    private let appSyncClient: AWSAppSyncClient!

/*
    Init if running app is using SwiftUI Content View
*/
    init(talks: [ListTodosQuery.Data.ListTodo.Item]) {
        self.appSyncClient = nil
        self.listTalks = talks
    }
}
```

Is it possible that Apple has changed the class name?
How do I find that out?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`BindableObject` has been renamed `ObservableObject`

```
BindableObject is replaced by the ObservableObject protocol from the Combine framework. (50800624)
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_13_release_notes